# How do I view operators in a Notify Operator task in a Maintenance Plan?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, maintenance-plans, database-mail

In the past, we have added each DBA to a Notify Operator task on failure **in Maintenance Plans** ranging from scheduled backups to indexing and occasionally one-off operations. One of our DBAs recently left the company and we removed her email account. We also removed her from the list of operators in SQL Agent. However, we have a number of SQL Server servers and instances installed and it would be tedious to go through each maintenance plan on each of those instances to find if she is on the list manually. Is there a way to query each maintenance plan from either within SSMS or PowerShell? We're using SQL Server 2008R2 thru 2014.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find pages explaining [how Maintenance Plans write](http://www.sqlballs.com/2013/01/how-do-you-query-maintenance-plan.html) and how to query them. Between that and a discussion on [how to use PowerShell to query XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18004693/powershell-retrieve-xml-data-from-column-in-sql-server-database), I think I have what I need to pull the maintenance plans in and query them. Since the SSIS package is essentially an XML document, I'm going to need to dust off (and tune up) my XQuery but here's what I have so far:

```
# TODO: Add a foreach statement, go through $ServerList, 
ouput to DBA database with date, server/instance info with $xmlDocs, 
turn below into a proper generic function

$MyQuery = "SELECT name
      ,CAST(CAST(packagedata as varbinary(max)) as xml) AS PackageSource
      ,packagetype
       ,id
      ,description
      ,createdate
  FROM msdb.dbo.sysssispackages WHERE [sysssispackages].[packagetype] = 6"
$server = '.'
$con = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$con.ConnectionString = "Server=$server; Database=msdb;Integrated Security=true"
$con.open()

$cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$cmd.CommandText = $MyQuery
$cmd.Connection = $con

$as = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$ds = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$as.SelectCommand = $cmd
$as.Fill($ds);

$xmlDocs = $ds.Tables[0] | %{ $_.PackageSource }
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways come to mind, there may be more. I prefer the second but that's just my opinion

```
Import-Module SQLPS -DisableNameChecking
Get-ChildItem SQLSERVER:\SQL\ServerNameHere\DEFAULT\jobserver\Jobs |Select Name, OperatorToEmail
```

The first line below loads the 2012 assembly since that's the version I'm running on my laptop, adjust to suit your needs.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName "Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"
$srvObject = new-object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server -ArgumentList 'ServerNameHere'
$srvObject.JobServer.Jobs| Select Name, OperatorToEmail
```

Comment: I ran both methods and they don't appear to work on maintenance plans because maintenance plans notify from within the SSIS package. This works for regular jobs and even SSIS packages with notify on failure/success on the job itself, but the maintenance plans themselves are all blank.